# how to host persistent data storage system on Amazon

Tags: amazon-ec2, hadoop, persistence, cloud, cloud-hosting

I am doing a project which deals with large amount of data. I am thinking to host that project on Ec2. I intend to use Hadoop to do the computing and some NoSql system (e.g. Hbase/Cassandra) to store the data. The NoSql system must be persistent (I don't want to lose my data). As far as I know, I need to spawn VMs to host Hadoop and NoSql stuffs. But the VMs are not persistent. Are there any other ways that I can host the data storage system persistently (not only the data, but the system which manages the data) and make use of the computation Amazon provides?

I guess my scenario is similar to people who host their databases persistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to look at using "Reserved Instances" and "Elastic Block Store"(EBS).

http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/reserved-instances/

http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/

If I understand your question correctly, you would want a reserved instance that you always leave running attached to an EBS volume for persistent storage of your data. EBS is able to make backup "snapshops" to S3 as well.

Comment: What I want is to have a persistent way to store the data and the running system which I can get the data out. In my understanding, "Reserved Instances" is an instance that I can keep for a while (at least 1 year). If that is the case, it could be a solution. BTW, how do people usually host their database on a Cloud?

Comment: There's no need to purchase a reserved instance until you've developed a system on EC2 and decide that you are going to use the same instance type for an extended period of time and you want to pay a bit less.  You can use EC2 instances for as long as you'd like without purchasing a reserved instance, and there is a good chance that you might want to change instance types before you're done.

Comment: AWS does not guarantee instances that are not reserved though. While its not extremely likely your on-demand instance will get "the boot"... from my understanding it is not out of the question either. Correct me if I am wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon provides a service named SimpleDB that you can use to store data persistently and flexibly. Depending on the requirements of your data, you might also be able to use Amazon S3.